# Internet Explorer windows that appear when I turn on the computer

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

When I turn on my computer(Windows 10), these Internet Explorer windows appear on the desktop. They say they are unable to view the web page of this link
I don't understand what they are and how can I solve this problem.
(I'm sorry but the language in the image is in Italian)

[image: web pages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the **Amazon Assistant for Internet Explorer**.

Uninstall Amazon assistant going to *Control Panel -> Programs and Features* or follow this [tutorial](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-resaaresources-dll104-error-on-internet-explorer/).

Answer (score 0):

**aaResources.dll** is related to the **Amazon Assistant for Internet Explorer 11**. You can disable or even uninstall it to fix your issue. **Uninstall Amazon Assistant** by going to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features you shouldn't have any further issues with this error and it won't be sitting in open programs. You can always reinstall Amazon Assistant if you need it later.